# My laptop makes a beep whenever I press 'C' and 'E' in quick succession while holding SHIFT. What is going on?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I've noticed that any time I type "CE" my laptop makes a beep. The behaviour occurs on Windows, not checked other on any other OS yet (might boot from a linux usb stick later and report back). Investigating that further revealed that:

- the order in which those are pressed doesn't matter, as long as it happens in quick succession or simultaneously
- it's only the C and E. I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour with any other key combination
- SHIFT must be pressed for both of them for the behaviour to occur

The problem is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/91873/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-type-shift-de-quickly) but doesn't generalise to all adjacent keys so I doubt the root cause is the same.

The laptop is a ThinkPad L380 Yoga.

Comment: CECEECCECEECCECECECECECE... (trying to reproduce... Not working...) Sorry about the theatrics, I know it's a real and valid question, but I also have a Lenovo laptop, so I thought I'd try. My keyboard is AZERTY, not QWERTY, so I suppose that could be factor too, but it looks like there's a faulty electrical connection in your keyboard.

Comment: Sure you don’t have your Sticky Keys on?

Comment: Does this also happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @Didier sounds odd (but not impossible) given that the OP and I have the same issue, both on Thinkpad series

Comment: @Valay_17 in my case, that is not the case.

Comment: Have you tried in Safe Mode, as harrymc suggested? It sounds (no pun intended) like a sytem beep to me, aka a big no-no from either your operating system or a hardware component when you try to do something *verboten*.

Comment: @Didier eh, working on it. Dealing with Bitlocker issues. For the moment I have "solved" the issue the hard way by disabling all keyboard beeps from the BIOS. Still curious what exactly is going on.

Comment: Beats me. System sounds are normal, in the sense that they are built in, either your operating system or at hardware level, for a reason, but it's the first time I've heard of a beep issued after pressing those two keys. Maybe a background app this keyboard combo is supposed to summon can't gain focus? I honestly don't know... :-(

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: This has always happened for me as well, but ONLY when holding the right shift key. It doesn't happen with the left shift key. On a Lenovo Thinkpad T14.

Answer (score 1):

For more troubleshooting, have you tried it on a separate attached keyboard? Perhaps one with high key rollover? If a separate keyboard does work, then there's a chance it's a hardware problem with your laptop's keyboard. [Diagram of keyboard circuits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePktS.png). You mentioned checking all key combinations, but that's 36 choose 2 = 630 combinations when only using the alphanumeric keys, so maybe you missed some. E and C are on the same column, so make sure to try E+3, C+3, or E+D or etc., as well. If these combinations beep, and a separate keyboard does not beep, there's a good chance it's a hardware problem.

Moreover, if this is Windows 10, there are more options than just disabling Sticky Keys; also check Filter Keys and Toggle Keys.

Lastly, have you updated your BIOS to its most recent version?:

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds502400][1](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds502400)

Ironically, if that doesn't work, I'd also suggest trying rolling back your BIOS to a previous version before the issue started, if it's a recent development. I'd only recommend rolling back if this problem is especially bothersome.

Comment: OP could also try the CE combination *in* BIOS or in another OS such as a live Linux distribution

Answer (score 0):

Only software can cause such a beep, most likely some product that you have installed.

The best test is to boot in Safe mode. If the beep disappears, then this is indeed
caused by some third-party product. If it doesn't, then there is some
problem with the keyboard.

If booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem, use [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). To avoid listing Microsoft products use the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*, *Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*. Turn off Startup entries in bunches, to drill down to the startup program that causes this problem. Reboot to test. Re-enable those that proved to be harmless.